# How to create new column in DataFrame based on other columns in Python Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have DataFrame like below:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({"col1" : ["a", "b", "c"], 
                     "binary" : [0, 1, 0]})
```

I would like to create and add new column in this `DataFrame` called `"new"` where if in column `"binary"` is 1 then I want to have data from `"col1"` in my created column `"new"`, but if in `"binary"` column is 0 then I want to have `np.NaN`. Below is the result which I really need based on my description and DatFrame above.

[image]

Comment: lots of ways to do this properly, `import numpy as np;df['new'] = np.where(df['binary'].eq(1), df['col1'],np.nan)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `where` from the `numpy` package and , and do:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"col1" : ["a", "b", "c"], "binary" : [0, 1, 0]})
df['new'] = np.where(df['binary']==1,df['col1'],np.nan)
```

which `prints`:

```
print(df)
  col1  binary  new
0    a       0  NaN
1    b       1    b
2    c       0  NaN
```

Comment: After your code i have this Error: TypeError: invalid type promotion

Comment: did you ```import pandas as pd```? It runs smoothly on mine, as shown above.

Comment: ok I already know, it was a mistake in data type of my column, Thank you! I choose your answer as the best